# Is it good practice to define a inner memeber accessor operator overload for CRTP template?

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns, crtp

This occurs to me that I can add

```cpp
template<typename T>
class ISock {
    public:
    Message Recv()  {
        return static_cast<T*>(this)->Recv();
    };
    ~ISock(){
        static_cast<T*>(this)->~ISock();
    };

    // use the following complementary...
    T* operator->(){
        return static_cast<T*>(this);
    };
    void Other override {
        (*this)->Other();
    }
};
```

This allows more flexibility in function definition and reduce boilerplates, for example, if I have

```cpp
class MockSock : ISock<MockSock> {
     public: 
     ...
     void peculiarFunction(int){
     ...
};
```

Then I may use the `peculiarFunction()` in defining `fn(ISock<MockSock>)` or even with `if constexpr` for specialization.
I am wondering whether it's a good practice to

1. provide a `inner<T>()` method
2. overload it as `operator->()` for simplicity in coding

Comment: `ISock` makes no sense at all. It has no functionality of its own, it forwards everything to the subclass, which you have anyway so you can just call the subclass functions directly. CRTP is a tool for *injecting implementations*, but `ISock` has nothing to inject. And look at the destructor. Where have you seen such a thing? Can you explain in plain English what it is doing?  (spoiler: it crashes)

Comment: What do you want to achieve? It seems like CRTP isn't required in this case.